# Colocar botão de "Ver Mais" JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma tabela que ao ter um campo com mais de 30 caracteres fica cortado e ao clicar na coluna, abre o texto restante, mas eu queria substituir o clique na coluna por um botão de ver mais, mas ao criar o código ele não me abre mais a coluna.

O que posso fazer para abrir o texto com um botão?

Código da tabela:

```
    if (strlen($desc_completa) > 30)
    {
        $str1 = substr($desc_completa, 0, 25) . '...';
        
        echo "<td><span>" . $str1 . "</span><span style='display:none'>" . $desc_completa . "</span>";
        echo "<button onclick='abrir(td)'>Ver Mais</button>"; 
        echo "</td>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td>{$desc_completa}</td>";
    }
```

Código JavaScript:

```
function abrir(td)
    {
        
        var spans = td.getElementsByTagName('span');
        spans[0].style.display = spans[0].style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
        spans[1].style.display = spans[1].style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No código não é possível ver onde foi definida a variável "td", então não é possível saber exatamente o problema.

Fiz uma alteração para evitar essa dependência e passei no lugar da variável "td" do `PHP` o `this` que é do próprio `javascript`.

Com isso, passamos para a função "abrir" a referência do botão, então a partir daí podemos pegar a referência da `TD` usando a função [parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement), que vai retornar o elemento "pai" do botão.

A seguir é o mesmo código, só fiz uma melhoria criando um variável para saber se o primeiro `span` está visível, a aproveitei que já tinha a referência do botão para mudar o texto para "Ver Menos"  :)

NOTA: tentei manter o código próximo ao original, mas uma melhoria que pode fazer é, no lugar mudar diretamente o style dos elementos, usar classes `CSS` para isso, usando a função [toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)

```js
function abrir(botao)
{
  var td = botao.parentElement;
  var spans = td.getElementsByTagName('span');
  var verMaisVisivel = spans[1].style.display == "none";
  
  if (verMaisVisivel) {
    spans[0].style.display = spans[0].style.display = "none";
    spans[1].style.display = spans[1].style.display = "block";
    botao.innerHTML = "Ver Menos";
  } else {
    spans[0].style.display = spans[0].style.display = "block";
    spans[1].style.display = spans[1].style.display = "none";
    botao.innerHTML = "Ver Mais";
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <span>Texto 1</span>
       <span style='display:none'>continuação do texto 1</span>
       <button onclick='abrir(this)'>Ver Mais</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <span>Texto 2</span>
       <span style='display:none'>continuação do texto 2</span>
       <button onclick='abrir(this)'>Ver Mais</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: mt obrigado pela sua ajuda, resolveu o meu problema certinho :)